# How to gain height after 21 years?(am racewalker)

Tags: exercise, nutrition

I am a racewalker and need longer legs! I am 21 years old and my height is 5'5". I am really concerned about my height. I do stretching daily and I have gained 1cm in 1 month. Can you please help me with other height gaining exercises? What should my diet? Also, can I do exercise with full stomach?

Comment: What are you concerned about?  Do want to join the NBA?

Comment: @SoylentGreen, I am racewalker, and good height(especially long legs) will truly benefit!

Comment: There is nothing you can do to increase your height once you have stopped growing.  Nothing natural, that is...

Comment: @JohnP Not really a dupe - in the other question its a 15year old girl who presumably has some growing left to do. At 21, growth plates start to fuse and will make extra high improbable.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr - Basic question - How do I increase my height - same answer, you don't, it's genetic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be better answered if you give what is your *reason* for wanting to grow taller.  Then we can address how to help you solve what you think is your "problem" with being short.

But also consider, how many inches do you think you can gain?  Suppose you could gain three inches (doubtful). Where would it come from?  Spinal lengthening?  That would reduce the integrity of your spine.  Leg lengthening?  Not really feasible at this point.   And would you be happy at 5'8"?  I know people who are 5'10" and want to be taller.

Inner character is so much more important than outward physical attributes.  Lots of people are tall and still have problems dating, getting jobs, being social, etc.  It's no panacea.

Comment: Sure, sir. Sorry for being late, but I am racewalker, and thus want longer legs, will you please suggest according to it, something?

Comment: And thank you so much for making me feel happy:)

Comment: What evidence do you have that indicates longer legs will improve your performance?  And I'm not talking about "all those taller people are beating me..." because there's surely some tall people behind you thinking, "yeah those shorter people are beating me, but that's because they have that unfair XYZ advantage because of their shortness."  Give cited references on both tallness and shortness in relation to advantage in athletic performance.  That's your homework.  :)